# Calculating sha3 of address in solidity vs web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

`sha3` of address-type argument calculated in solidity

```
function get_sha() constant returns (address, bytes32) {
    return (msg.sender, sha3(msg.sender));
}
```

is different from that calculated in web3js using buffer constructed from hex representation of the argument:

- returned from contract:
  address: `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c`
  bytes32: `0xb1591967aed668a4b27645ff40c444892d91bf5951b382995d4d4f6ee3a2ce03`
- returned by web3js:
  `> web3.sha3(Buffer.from('ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', 'hex').toString())`
  `'0xd53a2663473d029b80bddef493a064cc91bad113e4a61353b243b769c6909222'`

They match if I compare sha3s of string-type arguments like `"a"`, but don't match in case of address-type argument. I also tried to pad string inside `Buffer.from(...)` with 24 zeros on the left and on the right, so that it would represent 32 bytes, but the result is still incorrect.

How can I make web3's value match that of solidity's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `web3.sha3('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c')` or `web3.sha3('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', { encoding: 'hex' })`

Comment: Thanks, second variant with encoding works correctly. Do you happen to know why it didn't work with buffer? how does it get parsed in this case?

Comment: I'm guessing that [`sha3`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/sha3.js#L26) doesn't accept buffers, only strings.

Comment: This is why I use `toString()` on the buffer...

Comment: Wrong encoding on the string, perhaps?  Try using your original approach, but with `toString('ascii')` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either, I also tried `latin1` and other options from node.js docs

Answer (score 3):

One of my friend fixed this issue by making some changes in original [solidity-sha3](https://github.com/raineorshine/solidity-sha3) package which was created to match the behavior of sha3 in Solidity and web3.sha3 but still there were some issues.

Now, this Nodejs [package](https://github.com/nalinranjan/solidity-sha3) and solidity's sha3 behaves same.

In order to use it, you will have to include it inside package.json as shown below -

```
"solidity-sha3": "https://github.com/nalinranjan/solidity-sha3/tarball/master"
```

and then run

> npm install

After that if you want to use solidity-sha3 package in your test cases, you can import it like this -

```
const sha3 = require('solidity-sha3').default;
```

Hope this helps.